# Squeel iterating through an array with OR in Where block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel, squeel

I have the following query in Squeel:

```
languages = where{ (name == 'English') | 
 (name == 'Spanish')  | 
 (name == 'German')  | 
 (name == 'French')  | 
 ...
}
```

Which works fine but I was wodering if there was a way to iterate through an array with those values to make it easier to add and remove languages. Say I created and array:

```
languages_array = %w[ English Spanish French ... ]
```

Is there any way to iterate with Squeel in a Where block?

I've tried everything I can think of without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work

```
where{name.in(languages_array)}
```

Comment: Great. I never even thought of using `IN`. What an idiot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `squeel` for this type of query: `where(name: languages_array)` will do what you need - it'll translate to

```
WHERE name IN ('English', 'Spanish', 'French', ...)
```

which is probably what you need.

Comment: That's true, but when you are using a layer like *squeel* I guess it makes sense to use it for everything, otherwise you'll end up with a funny mixture of queries.

Comment: This is true, I'm trying to stick to one or the other but it's proving difficult. I even have had to write some straight `find_by_sql` scary queries because I found no way to do them in Rails.